# Typescript let a Function return Generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Heyho is it possible that a generic class have a function that returns its generic type?

```
  export class RmqtAction<T, K> {
    action: string;
    payload = () => T;
    returnType = () => K;
  }
```

something like this as i want to create Typesafe actions between my
microservices.
(i only need typesafety in compiletime not runtime)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTDuEMDsBcAJoPawMYCcCm5rtuWBzdSdVAS2VgEFlpSFIAoWZ2dADwAcFU5kAbcAGdBsAEoBbAI7RqtegB4AKgBpYAaQB8sAN5MW+8DTqQAXLEHQykfAG49+5hwCuAIz7lYHcAE8+CcAAmsAC8sAAUggji6GaKAJQhWtDeHOgIAGbmUeh2DizObh4Y0E6okCHhkdFmagnBSSlpmVU5DPYOyPQWqE403GGGcqbmlqTWCbp5edAAFqSCAHSDxhXL9LlTAL7t22177Fw8KF1wigCSALIAogD6iqKUAMJqZwByAOI371eKNwCqAGUrqIbgAJADyf1EALMEmksmM8j02lgpACZkgTnELhIsE2ymRqPRsEx2Nx2y0oWIoDEUhkRgUKLRGKxONQeNUTOJpLZeI0YQA5NgLAK4nYGAduLwTvB0BYSLFLrd7k8Xh8vj9-kCQRCoQCFl5fP4AmE6jpmbAAIwABm2QA

Comment: What do you mean by "returns its type"? Types don't exist at runtime and types are not values, so the code you've written doesn't work. Can you show an example of how you'd want to use this?

Comment: ```
export class RmqtAction<T, K> {
  action: string;
  public payload = (some: T) => typeof some;
  public return = (some: K) => typeof some;

  constructor(action: string) {
    this.action = action;
  }
}
```
than i want to create the action

```
export const TIME_TRACKING_GET_USER_HOURS: RmqtAction<
  { id: number },
  { id: number }
> = new RmqtAction<{ id: number }, { id: number }>('test');
```
and later when i use the action in the code i want to use its type
```
export const tester: TIME_TRACKING_GET_USER_HOURS.payload()
```

Comment: for better understanding a playground link

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTDuEMDsBcAJoPawMYCcCm5rtuWBzdSdVAS2VgEFlpSFIAoWZ2dADwAcFU5kAbcAGdBsAEoBbAI7RqtegB4AKgBpYAaQB8sAN5MW+8DTqQAXLEHQykfAG49+5hwCuAIz7lYHcAE8+CcAAmsAC8sAAUggji6GaKAJQhWtDeHOgIAGbmUeh2DizObh4Y0E6okCHhkdFmagnBSSlpmVU5DPYOyPQWqE403GGGcqbmlqTWCbp5edAAFqSCAHSDxhXL9LlTAL7t22177Fw8KF1wigCSALIAogD6iqKUAMJqZwByAOI371eKNwCqAGUrqIbgAJADyf1EALMEmksmM8j02lgpACZkgTnELhIsE2ymRqPRsEx2Nx2y0oWIoDEUhkRgUKLRGKxONQeNUTOJpLZeI0YQA5NgLAK4nYGAduLwTvB0BYSLFLrd7k8Xh8vj9-kCQRCoQCFl5fP4AmE6jpmbAAIwABm2QA

Comment: Please put your example code as plaintext in the question itself and not only as an external link (although external links are helpful as a supplement).  The type parameter `K` is usually used for keylike types; if it's just some other type, it would be more conventional to use `U` or something (`T` and `U` are like the `foo` and `bar` of the type parameter world).

Comment: Does the class actually have any useful dependencies on those type parameters?  Does it ever, say, accept a value of the "payload" type and return a value of the "return" type?    If so then you could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WybJJw).  Right now the class seems to have no useful dependency on those type parameters, so any suggestion I make here is going to be weird and artificial.

Comment: this looks close to right,
For clarification i need this for my microservices which are communicating over Rabbitmq, it works like this

microservice A is sending an Action with the payload to the Rabbitmq broker
microservice B listens for the Action and takes the payload and calls a function with it and returns it back to the broker 
the broker than returns it back to microservice A.

At first i wrote the payload everytime without any typing (the broker accepts any as payload) and it didnt worked out pretty well thats why i want to link the typings to the Action.

Comment: Basicly i want to know when i Use an action which type the payload has (so i can fill it correctly) and also which return i can expect.

Comment: TypeScript only really supports a *structural* dependency on a type; if you have nothing inside your class declaration which actually does anything with values corresponding your type parameters, then there's no direct support for what you want.  There's a request at [ms/TS#17588](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17588) allowing "associated types" but this is not implemented.  Right now you can fake it/emulate it via "phantom properties" which will not actually exist at runtime. Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nabzom) in your case. Does that work for you? If so I can write up an answer.

Comment: Hey a little bit late but that was exactly what i needed :), Thank you very much!